# Default value in Talend ETL Tool

Tags: talend

I'm importing data from MS Excel to MySQL Database using Talend ETL Tool, few columns might not have data in this case i need to consider default value. 
how to give default value in talend ETL tool?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way should look like this:
`row1.yourField == null ? "defaultValue" : row1.yourField`
You'll have to do this for each concerned field with the appropriate default values.
Default value on database side will not work for the fields which participate to the query, so you have to transform the value on client side.
Hope this helps.
TRF

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing an expression in the Tmap component of Talend to map the nulls with some default value.

```
row1.column=null ? “Default value” : row1.column
```

This needs to be done for every field wherein the mapping with default value is needed.

You may also refer the below link for a similar issue:
https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=33623